# Ошибка компиляции регулярного выражения: unmatched parentheses

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

В онлайн проверках все работает, а `php` выдает ошибку. Строка в которой ищем:

`test/modules/test/controllers`
нужно получить `test` между `modules` и `controllers`

```
if(preg_match("/modules\\(.*?)\\controllers/",$text,$matches)) 
echo $matches[1];
```

при выполнении получаю:

```
warning: preg_match(): Compilation failed: unmatched parentheses at offset 12
```

Comment: а заменить `\\` на `\/`?

Comment: Заменил, warning пропал, поиск не работает.

Comment: нет, достаточно просто прочитать вопрос.

Comment: Вот [так надо](http://ideone.com/Y9JBvD), заменить ленивый квантификатор на символьный класс и использовать 4 знака косой черты для нахождения данного символа во входной строке.

Answer (score 4):

Тут надо писать не 2, а 4 слеша. Потому что выходит, что ты в регулярке экранируешь скобки.

А нет, пробуй

```
if(preg_match("/modules\\/(.*?)\\/controllers/",$text,$matches)) 
echo $matches[1];
```

**Обновление**

Не знаю как у Вас, но у меня скрипт

```
<?
$text = 'test/modules/test/controllers';
if (preg_match("/modules\\/(.*?)\\/controllers/",$text,$matches)) echo $matches[1];
?>
```

выводит

> test

Comment: если 3 или 4 слеша ошибок нет но и не ищет ничего.

Comment: нет, поиск не работает.

Answer (score 3):

```
if(preg_match('%modules/(.+)/controllers%iu', $text, $matches)) 
  echo $matches[1];
```

Comment: не работает, результат пустой

Comment: @AndreyS, все прекрасно работает. И тут https://regex101.com/r/gS7eZ5/1 и на localhost при тесте в php.

Comment: Прошу прощения это видимо я опечатался, строка в которой ищем должна выглядеть так 'test\modules\test\controllers' здесь все хорошо https://regex101.com/r/uL4jQ2/2 а в php не работает

Comment: @AndreyS, используйте совет из другого ответа.

Answer (score 0):

В приведенном регулярном выражении двойной знак косой черты экранирует открывающую скобку, т.е. `\\(` - это обычный знак `(`. Закрывающая скобка же не экранирована, т.е. парсер регулярного выражения видит маркер конца подмаски (группы). Так как открывающего маркера нет, генерируется исключение.

Замените ленивый квантификатор на символьный класс (если в искомой подстроке не должно быть слешей) и используйте 4 знака косой черты для нахождения данного символа во входной строке.

Используйте [такое выражение](https://regex101.com/r/wK7rT9/2):

```
$re = "/modules\\\\([^\\\\]*)\\\\controllers/";
```

См. [пример PHP-кода](http://ideone.com/Y9JBvD).

Используйте модификатор `/u`, если необходимо работать с Unicode-строками (не `/U`, это модификатор смены режима жадности).

Если нужно найти подстроку, содержащую знаки обратной черты от `modules\` до `\controllers`, придется использовать [оригинальное выражение](https://regex101.com/r/wK7rT9/1):

```
$re = "/modules\\\\(.*?)\\\\controllers/u";
```